# Double click selecting word in Word / Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-word

Is there any way to customize what is selected when you double click on a word in Word 2010 / Outlook 2010?

Fr'instance, I might copy a variable name into an email:

m_iMyInteger

However, if I then wish to copy that text and I double click on it, it only selects "iMyInteger", seeing the underscore as a whitespace.

How can I change that behaviour?

Comment: PS - double clicking on it in IE also exhibits the same effect...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible, short of writing some VBA macro in Word to intercept the mouse click and select the word as required.

I did find a thread which [discussed language options affecting the delimiter characters](http://www.techrepublic.com/forum/questions/101-313381), but I'm not sure it's relevant to your issue.

In short - it's likely to take far more time and effort to try and investigate / develop a solution than it would be to just select words by click and drag rather than double-click.

Comment: You can't assume this without knowing how often the asker double clicks selects an underscore containing word per year...